# How to make a preview box using LinkPreview API?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api-linkpreview

Like below image link preview shown, it's an image of what I expect in same way as soon as user inserts a link in the textarea.

From link preview site, I am getting `image`,`url`,`description` of site in console window, but I want to display inside a `<div>` tag.

[image: link preview image of website]

html:

```
<div class="show_lnk"></div>

 <textarea class="form-control" placeholder=""  id="url" name="user_status"></textarea>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery("textarea[name*='user_status']").blur(function () {
    var target = jQuery(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.linkpreview.net",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {q: target, key: '5a2e292e7d25bb63a2d3b4c63524cd10abe39420dc68c'},
        success: function (response) {
            var data=response;
            $(".show_lnk").html('<img src="'+data.image+'" style="width:30px;height:30px;" ');
            console.log(data.image);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: actually i want link preview like facebook so i  tried this one but after implementing  this code is working for only youtube url perfectly but i am developing site so need exactly facebook link preview system can u please help me for this if u have please give me any source code for link preview i had tried so many github plugins but none  of them is working

Comment: @mickmackusa pls guide me about link preview system about how to handle this i am eagerly waiting for this.

Comment: i am creating website in which user will post one url so using jquery or  other trickyway it should make preview of link for example if add https://google.co.in then it should generate image  clickable link i am new to jquery language so don't have grip how to do this same as facebook link preview system

Comment: ok i will update now just give me five minutes

Comment: @mickmackusa i have edited my question please view it once and guide me ,image is to indicate  what i expect .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure where you are stuck, but this will display the response data in some simple tags inside of a dedicated `<div>`.  How you manipulate the css is totally up to you.

I've pre-loaded `google.com` into the textarea, so the only thing you have to do is trigger the function by causing a `blur` event (tab or whatever).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("textarea[name*='user_status']").blur(function () {
    var target = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.linkpreview.net",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {q: target, key: '5a2e292e7d25bb63a2d3b4c63524cd10abe39420dc68c'},
      success: function (response) {
        $("#show_lnk").html('<img src="'+response.image+'"><h3>'+response.title+'</h3><h4>'+response.description+'</h4><a href="'+response.url+'">'+response.url+'</a>');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 25px;
}

#show_lnk img {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" id="url" name="user_status">google.com</textarea>     
<div id="show_lnk"></div>
```

Comment: @Nick talk to the OP.

Comment: @Nick Really?  Downvote my correct and proven answer?  -2 points does not hurt me, you are only damaging StackOverflow when you downvote correct answers.

Comment: @faiz If you have a new question, you should post a new question.  The format on StackOverflow is meant to keep questions contained/isolated for easy searching.  If you keep extending a single question, it can pose an unfair expectation on a single volunteer.

Comment: @faiz I don't think there is much that can be done about that.